# What is a capacitive screen sensing?

Tags: sensor, applied-physics

What should be a properties of a body so a contact with it can be detected by a capacitive touchscreen or a touchpad?

Comment: Not sure this passes the "too basic" criteria, can be answered from Wikipedia surely? Vote to close.

Comment: Wikipedia is too basic here; I'm pretty sure someone in topic could elaborate a lot more.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing), capacitative sensors detect things with conductive or dielectric properties; so to me, that means these sensors detect a contrast in the electrical properties between your finger, say, and the air around it.

I just tested this out on my touchpad with a metal ruler and if I pushed down, I got a little bit of response.

Comment: Try whit glass an report

Comment: I tried with a wooden chopstick and nothing happened.

Comment: This reference from Wikipedia seems good.  See http://www.lionprecision.com/tech-library/technotes/cap-0020-sensor-theory.html